# Setting the DataSource to an ASP.NET DropDownList in html is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to set DataSource of a DropDownlist as in the following code (in a .aspx file):

```
<tr>
    <td class="Col1">
        <asp:Label ID="lbCompany" runat="server" Text="Thuộc công ty:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td class="Col2">
        <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlCompany" DataSource="<%# GetCompanies() %>" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td class="Col3">
        <asp:Label ID="lbCompanyError" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the C# code behind, in aspx.cs file, I declared the GetCompanies() method like this:

```
protected IEnumerable<Company> GetCompanies()
{
    using (var bkDb = new BrickKilnDb())
    {
        return bkDb.Companies.ToList();
    }
}
```

But at runtime, the DropDownList is Empty. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically to bind the dropdownlist we are using following code try this.

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = GetCompanies();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```